# Field naming: naming guidelines VS CLS compliance

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

As far as I have understood the [C# Capitalization Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx), property-related fields should be named in lowerCamelCase the same way their corresponding properties are named in PascalCase.

```
public class Person {
    protected int ageFullYears;
    public int AgeFullYears{
        get {
            return ageFullYears;
        }
    }
}
```

Another most common practice is the same as the first, but the field name is preceded by the underscore.

```
public class Person {
    protected object _ageFullYears;
    public object AgeFullYears{
        get {
            return _ageFullYears;
        }
    }
}
```

However, as many have noticed, neither practice is [CLS-compliant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#naming), as CLS compliance rules require that different class members' names should differ with more than just case, and also require that

> The first character of an identifier can be any Unicode uppercase letter, lowercase letter, title case letter, modifier letter, other letter, or letter number.

Whatever the argumentation against using protected instance fields may be, they are the language's reality that sometimes has it's uses.

So, basically, the question is this: is there a CLS-compliant de-facto standard of naming property-related instance fields in C#?

Comment: You are mixing it up pretty badly.  The naming guidelines started as an internal document at Microsoft that set standards to be used by their programmers when they worked on .NET code.  They published it on the theory that it might be useful to customers, whether you make it your own guideline is entirely up to your dev team.  The CLSCompliant rules are clearly stated, it only sets rules for the character set and ambiguity caused by casing, it does *not* forbid a leading underscore or camel-casing.  When you see a leading underscore then you probably found a programmer that likes Resharper.

Comment: @HansPassant I never meant to say that naming guidelines were a "de-jure" standard of C# coding. However, it's the closest thing we have to language-wide coding conventions, and that closest thing is not CLS compliant.

Comment: You'll need to be a *lot* more explicit about your theory that it is not CLSCompliant.  You linked to the rules, three of them fall in the "Naming conventions" category.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for feedback, I've corrected and elaborated my question.

Comment: The section you quoted is a verbatim copy of the Unicode technical report.  There is something fishy about it, quoted: "It is a natural extension of the identifier syntax used in C and other programming languages".  The C language has a very long history of allowing leading underscores.  It is in fact a *requirement* to use it in certain cases.  The only way to rescue it is the ambiguity in it talking about using non-ASCII characters in an identifier.  In practice it is not a known problem and the compiler certainly won't complain.